# BS4 grabbing the contents of a tag with an unusual attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website using BS4 (we have permission to scrape but no control over the html) and they've changed the formatting slightly. This change means that I can't figure out a way to grab one small segment.

This is the html

```
<p class="icons"> 
<span data-caption=" Bed"> 8</span>            
<span data-caption=" Bath">4</span>            
<span data-caption=" Car">4</span>            
<span data-caption="">1090m&sup2;        
</p>
```

I'm trying to grab the number of Beds using

```
bed = soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"})
```

and then clean it up using

```
bed = bed.replace(" ","")
```

but each time bed is set to none. Any insights into how to grab it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `replace` method *on the element*:

```
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"})
<span data-caption=" Bed"> 8</span>
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"}).replace(' ', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

BeautifulSoup lets you find elements by their name only, as an attribute. Any attribute BeautifulSoup doesn't understand is turned into a *search* for an element by that name.

Because you used the name `.replace` on an element, BeautifulSoup is trying to find the `<replace>` element. There is no such element so `None` is returned:

```
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"}).replace is None
True
```

All you needed to do was use the [`element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"}).get_text()
u' 8'
```

You can give it a `strip` keyword argument, set it to `True` to have the text elements stripped for you (spaces removed from start and end):

```
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"}).get_text(strip=True)
u'8'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip` function to strip all the leading or trailing spaces. `.text` helps you to get the content of that particular tag.

```
>>> s = """<p class="icons"> 
<span data-caption=" Bed"> 8</span>            
<span data-caption=" Bath">4</span>            
<span data-caption=" Car">4</span>            
<span data-caption="">1090m&sup2;        
</p> """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find("span",{"data-caption":" Bed"}).text.strip()
'8'
```